# How to set up a basic single-zone irrigation system

Tags: water, sprinkler-system, irrigation

I am thinking of installing a very basic irrigation system (one zone) to water the area but I do not know where to start.

Below is a basic diagram of the area I want to water. I want the irrigation system to be connected to the hose bibb in my backyard. I cannot lay a pipe in the area where the shrubs are since it is beyond my property line (the shrubs are in a green belt and they were planted by the previous owner). The red line in the diagram below shows where I would like to bury the pipe.

What would it take with things I can buy at Home Depot? Should I go with PVC, pex, etc.? Can I simply bury a PVC pipe, connect the sprinkler heads and then connect to pipe to the hose bibb?

Thank you!

[image: to setup a basic irrigation system]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Home Depot has an entire section dedicated to irrigation. They have a neat little DIYer setup called orbit. It uses 1/2 pvc tubing and barb fittings. My nearest Home Depot sells pop up heads that will shoot water 15'.

**Here's an idea of what orbit irrigation has**[image]www.amazon.ca

**Here's a bit about the orbit pop-up**
Model # 91561 Store SKU # 1000743815

> Orbit's Voyager II Professional Gear Drive is the best in class of all gear drive pop-up sprinkler heads. It is the #1 consumer choice for medium to large area gear drive sprinkler heads. It's versatility allows coverage from a 25 ft. up to a 52 ft. radius in a part- to full-circle spray pattern. The gear drive rotor ensures even and complete water coverage as well as a quiet spray. A filter protects the nozzle from clogging and is easily accessible for cleaning. It is compatible with all major brands of gear drive rotors including Rainbird, Hunter, and Toro.
>   *www.homedepot.com*

You could probably do the whole yard with 2 or 3 of those.

Comment: By code in many places, if you have a permanent sprinkler buried you also need to have a **backflow prevention valve** which is a simple device to make sure that muddy water doesn’t back up into your domestic water.   If your outside temperature also has the risk of dropping below freezing you need a blowout valve so you can “winterize” the system.   Often times these two things are combined into a single device and they’re extremely common and easy to find.

Comment: That's a good point. However, to begin I am planning to connect it to the hose bibb. The hose bibb already has a backflow preventer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Start here:  [Irrigation Tutorials](https://irrigationtutorials.com/)

Much of this is more than you want to know.  You will be mostly interested in how to do supply lines and so on.

Quick and dirty stuff can be as simple as a Y branch on your tap, a hose connector timer, and half inch drip line (actually .700 or .710" outside diameter) line.  you can excavate for 1/2" line with the claws of a hammer, putting in 1" below the ground.  PE pipe is pretty tolerant of freeze thaw cycles even with water in the line.

If you use drippers, use two per shrub so that if one gets clogged it's not the end of the world.  There are bunches of micro sprinklers that you can use to water areas of a few feet to 10 feet across.